# Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'cache_dir must be a directory'

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached, wamp

I am new to Zend and I have to work on previously done project to add some functionality.
Below are the cache specifications in application.ini file.

```
cache.frontend.type = Core
cache.frontend.options.lifetime = 7200
cache.frontend.options.automatic_serialization = true
cache.frontend.options.cache_id_prefix = proj_name
cache.frontend.options.cache = true


cache.backend.type = Memcached
cache.backend.options.servers.1.host = 127.0.0.1
cache.backend.options.servers.1.port = 11211
cache.backend.options.servers.1.persistent = true
cache.backend.options.servers.1.weight = 1
cache.backend.options.servers.1.timeout = 5
cache.backend.options.servers.1.retry_interval = 15
logsdb.params.dbname = dataLink
```

I have installed memcache and it works fine.  But the following error occurs when I want to start project.

Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'cache_dir must be a directory'

I tried to find some answers in google but none of the solutions worked. Please help me with this. I work on WAMP 2.1

Comment: Do you have full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but if you use an "new" version of Zend Framework (1.8+?), than you have to use
CacheManager in your application.ini to setup the cache.

For memcache it should look like this:

```
resources.cachemanager.myache.frontend.name = Core
resources.cachemanager.mycache.frontend.options.automatic_serialization = On
resources.cachemanager.mycache.backend.name = Memcached

resources.cachemanager.mycache.backend.options.servers.1.host = 
resources.cachemanager.mycache.backend.options.servers.1.port = 1
resources.cachemanager.mycache.backend.options.servers.2.host = 
resources.cachemanager.mycache.backend.options.servers.2.port =
```

And somewhere in your **Controller** to get the Cache:

```
 $cacheManager = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('cachemanager');
      $myCache = $cacheManager->getCache('mycache');
```

Or **anyhwhere** in your code (i dont like this way)

```
$cacheManager = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                       ->getParam('bootstrap')
                       ->getResource('cachemanager');

$myCache = $cacheManager->getCache('mycache');
```